# Limit to jQuery's fadeOut, and Hide effects?

Tags: jquery

I have this big object that I'd like to fadeOut and its not working at all. It works on a smaller subset of the object, but I'm wondering if there is some internal limit on how big the element can be.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Showing the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Got it. There's no limit (atleast I haven't hit it yet).

If you have a div container that's not really defined (height/width) then its not going to work. An arbitrary height and width should do it!